# SerenityRest: How to handle response with no content

Tags: java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I have a serenity Step method that sends a REST API request.  It's a POST request to create a resource.  I get a 201 in the response and don't expect any content.

```
        return SerenityRest.rest().given()
               .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
               .log().all()
               .body(requestbody)
               .post("/somepath/v1/resource")
               .then().log().all();
```

My tests all pass however the report generation fails because the response to the above request has no content.  This is the error I get in the Maven build

```
Jan 18, 2021 8:11:32 PM freemarker.log._JULLoggerFactory$JULLogger error
SEVERE: Error executing FreeMarker template
FreeMarker template error:
Java method "net.thucydides.core.reports.html.Formatter.renderText(String)" threw an exception when invoked on net.thucydides.core.reports.html.Formatter object "net.thucydides.core.reports.html.Formatter@286860d7"; see cause exception in the Java stack trace.

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${formatter.renderText(restQuery.resp...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "restQueryData" at line 348, column 41]
    - Reached through: @restQueryData restQuery=step.restQue...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "step_details" at line 418, column 37]
    - Reached through: @step_details step=step step_number=s...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "write_step" at line 242, column 17]
    - Reached through: @write_step step=nestedStep step_numb...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "write_step" at line 252, column 25]
    - Reached through: @write_step step=nestedStep step_numb...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "write_step" at line 252, column 25]
    - Reached through: @write_step step=step step_number=ste...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" at line 464, column 17]
----

Java stack trace (for programmers):
----
freemarker.core._TemplateModelException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]
    at freemarker.ext.beans._MethodUtil.newInvocationTemplateModelException(_MethodUtil.java:311)
    at freemarker.ext.beans._MethodUtil.newInvocationTemplateModelException(_MethodUtil.java:275)
    at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel.exec(SimpleMethodModel.java:80)
    at freemarker.core.MethodCall._eval(MethodCall.java:62)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:78)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.evalAndCoerceToString(Expression.java:82)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:41)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:48)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:184)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.invoke(Environment.java:701)
    at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:84)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:48)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:184)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.invoke(Environment.java:701)
    at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:84)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:184)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.invoke(Environment.java:701)
    at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:84)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlockInner(IteratorBlock.java:268)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlock(IteratorBlock.java:220)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:194)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:572)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:78)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:64)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:48)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:184)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.invoke(Environment.java:701)
    at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:84)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlockInner(IteratorBlock.java:268)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlock(IteratorBlock.java:220)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:194)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:572)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:78)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:64)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:48)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:184)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.invoke(Environment.java:701)
    at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:84)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlockInner(IteratorBlock.java:268)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlock(IteratorBlock.java:220)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:194)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:572)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:78)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:64)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:302)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.templates.FreemarkerReportTemplate.merge(FreemarkerReportTemplate.java:42)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.html.Merger$MergeBuilder.to(Merger.java:37)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.html.HtmlAcceptanceTestReporter.generateReportPage(HtmlAcceptanceTestReporter.java:144)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.html.HtmlAcceptanceTestReporter.generateReportFor(HtmlAcceptanceTestReporter.java:130)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.ReportService.generateReportFor(ReportService.java:221)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.ReportService.access$100(ReportService.java:35)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.ReportService$1.run(ReportService.java:157)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.html.Formatter.renderText(Formatter.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.invokeMethod(BeansWrapper.java:1458)
    at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel.exec(SimpleMethodModel.java:71)
    ... 87 more

10942 [pool-1-thread-5] WARN net.thucydides.core.reports.templates.FreemarkerReportTemplate - Report generation failed
FreeMarker template error:
Java method "net.thucydides.core.reports.html.Formatter.renderText(String)" threw an exception when invoked on net.thucydides.core.reports.html.Formatter object "net.thucydides.core.reports.html.Formatter@286860d7"; see cause exception in the Java stack trace.

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${formatter.renderText(restQuery.resp...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "restQueryData" at line 348, column 41]
    - Reached through: @restQueryData restQuery=step.restQue...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "step_details" at line 418, column 37]
    - Reached through: @step_details step=step step_number=s...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "write_step" at line 242, column 17]
    - Reached through: @write_step step=nestedStep step_numb...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "write_step" at line 252, column 25]
    - Reached through: @write_step step=nestedStep step_numb...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "write_step" at line 252, column 25]
    - Reached through: @write_step step=step step_number=ste...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" at line 464, column 17]
----

Java stack trace (for programmers):
----
freemarker.core._TemplateModelException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]
    at freemarker.ext.beans._MethodUtil.newInvocationTemplateModelException(_MethodUtil.java:311)
    at freemarker.ext.beans._MethodUtil.newInvocationTemplateModelException(_MethodUtil.java:275)
    at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel.exec(SimpleMethodModel.java:80)
    at freemarker.core.MethodCall._eval(MethodCall.java:62)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:78)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.evalAndCoerceToString(Expression.java:82)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:41)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:48)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:184)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.invoke(Environment.java:701)
    at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:84)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:48)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:184)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.invoke(Environment.java:701)
    at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:84)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:184)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.invoke(Environment.java:701)
    at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:84)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlockInner(IteratorBlock.java:268)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlock(IteratorBlock.java:220)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:194)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:572)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:78)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:64)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:48)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:184)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.invoke(Environment.java:701)
    at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:84)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlockInner(IteratorBlock.java:268)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlock(IteratorBlock.java:220)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:194)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:572)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:78)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:64)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:48)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:184)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.invoke(Environment.java:701)
    at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:84)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlockInner(IteratorBlock.java:268)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlock(IteratorBlock.java:220)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:194)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:572)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:78)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:64)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:302)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.templates.FreemarkerReportTemplate.merge(FreemarkerReportTemplate.java:42)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.html.Merger$MergeBuilder.to(Merger.java:37)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.html.HtmlAcceptanceTestReporter.generateReportPage(HtmlAcceptanceTestReporter.java:144)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.html.HtmlAcceptanceTestReporter.generateReportFor(HtmlAcceptanceTestReporter.java:130)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.ReportService.generateReportFor(ReportService.java:221)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.ReportService.access$100(ReportService.java:35)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.ReportService$1.run(ReportService.java:157)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.html.Formatter.renderText(Formatter.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.invokeMethod(BeansWrapper.java:1458)
    at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel.exec(SimpleMethodModel.java:71)
    ... 87 more
10945 [pool-1-thread-5] ERROR net.thucydides.core.reports.templates.FreemarkerReportTemplate - Syntax error in report template: Java method "net.thucydides.core.reports.html.Formatter.renderText(String)" threw an exception when invoked on net.thucydides.core.reports.html.Formatter object "net.thucydides.core.reports.html.Formatter@286860d7"; see cause exception in the Java stack trace.

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${formatter.renderText(restQuery.resp...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "restQueryData" at line 348, column 41]
    - Reached through: @restQueryData restQuery=step.restQue...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "step_details" at line 418, column 37]
    - Reached through: @step_details step=step step_number=s...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "write_step" at line 242, column 17]
    - Reached through: @write_step step=nestedStep step_numb...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "write_step" at line 252, column 25]
    - Reached through: @write_step step=nestedStep step_numb...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "write_step" at line 252, column 25]
    - Reached through: @write_step step=step step_number=ste...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" at line 464, column 17]
----
    - Failed at: ${formatter.renderText(restQuery.resp...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "restQueryData" at line 348, column 41]
    - Reached through: @restQueryData restQuery=step.restQue...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "step_details" at line 418, column 37]
    - Reached through: @step_details step=step step_number=s...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "write_step" at line 242, column 17]
    - Reached through: @write_step step=nestedStep step_numb...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "write_step" at line 252, column 25]
    - Reached through: @write_step step=nestedStep step_numb...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" in macro "write_step" at line 252, column 25]
    - Reached through: @write_step step=step step_number=ste...  [in template "freemarker/default.ftl" at line 464, column 17]


2 Scenarios (2 passed)
5 Steps (5 passed)
```

Anyone know how I handle this.  I can get around by using RestAssured instead of SerenityRest, but that then the REST request and response details are left out of the report.

When I do this with REST APIs where response has content, there is no issue.